# Mapping Cosmic microwave background onto a sphere

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want to map image of Cosmic microwave background  onto a sphere

I tried this:

```
i= Import["http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/\images/2013/03/planck_cmb/12583930-4-eng-GB/Planck_CMB.jpg"] 

ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},

ContourStyle -> Texture[i], Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: and the question is?..

Comment: Why not try to search for an *equirectangular* projection of the CMBR?